# Arreglar fechas introducidas con formato dd/MM/YYYY

Tags: java, date

Con Java en lugar de grabar en la base de datos las fechas con el formato `dd/MM/yyyy` he usado el año en mayúsculas (`dd/MM/YYYY`). Me gustaría revertir lo grabado, y poder transformar las fechas introducidas erróneamente por las fechas correctas, pero no he encontrado ninguna forma ni patrón para lograrlo. ¿Alguien podría decirme la forma de hacerlo? Debajo tenéis una muestra de lo que hice.

```
String FORMATO_FECHA = "dd/MM/YYYY";
String fechaStr = "14/06/2014";
System.out.println("FECHA ORIGINAL: " + fechaStr);
Date fechaDate = null;
try {

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMATO_FECHA);
    fechaDate = format.parse(fechaStr);

    System.out.println("FECHA TRANSFORMADA: " + fechaDate);//Esta es la fecha que he grabado en base de datos

} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: quieres deshacer los cambios en la bd?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es cambiar los datos en la BD, no tiene nada que ver con Java, pienso yo. Dinos que BD usas: Sql, Mysql...

Comment: Y cuales son las fechas introducidas erroneamente? te refieres a que si ?introudcen en java 2014/06/14, te lo transforme a tu formato (14/06/2014)

Comment: Tu base de dato este campo es un varchar? Es mejor hacer un procedimiento por base de datos, es mas efectivo que hacer un programa, cuando en bbdd existen los procedimiento, function y package :D

Comment: Realmente me da igual como solucionar el problema, si en base de datos,  con Java, .... Una vez que tenga la solución haré un proceso masivo para arreglar los datos.

Comment: Puedes mostrar un ejemplo con el dato Erroneo y el dato esperado (el dato correcto esperado),  lo ideal será crear un sp o un query que haga el update, pero debes indicar que bd usas y que tipo de campo estás usando para almacenar

Comment: Hola, puedes ser más claro con lo que deseas por favor, necesitamos eso para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Como yo se lo que me está pasando, puede que no explique bien lo que me pasa. No es un error de base de datos, el error fue en Java. Lo que hice fue al construir con un String en formato "dd/MM/yyyy" un java.util.Date use el formato "dd/MM/YYYY", y lo que da es una fecha que no tiene nada que ver con la fecha original. Mirando la documentación de Java, el carácter "Y" tiene que ver con el día de la semana, pero no es el año. Por eso lo que busco es si alguien puede decirme como puedo "desparsear"  el Date y poder coger la fecha original.

Comment: como deseas que salga tu fecha, dame un ejemplo

Comment: Con que me devuelva la fecha original me vale. En el ejemplo que he dada antes, que "14/06/2014" al aplicar el formato de fecha "dd/MM/YYYY" que me la transforma en "30/12/2013" me gustaria poder "desparsear" el "30/12/2013" y que vuelva a ser "14/06/2014"